# making dll injector error object reference is required for the non static field method or property injector.SI(uint, string)

Tags: c#

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'injector.SI(uint, string)' I dont really understand what is the error or the mistake (Visual Studio C# windows form app it would be a really big help if anyone can fix this because I cant find the solution at all Ive been searching for quite a bit of time but still cant find any solution

```
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Hoshiyomi.functions
{
    public partial class injector : Form
    {
        public injector()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Process[] PC = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => (long)p.MainWindowHandle !=0).ToArray();
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            foreach (Process p in PC)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
            }
        }
        private void injector_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        }

        private static string DLLP { get; set; }
        private void flatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();
                OFD.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
                OFD.Title = "NotWeeb | Locate DLL";
                OFD.DefaultExt = "dll";
                OFD.Filter = "DLL Files (*.dll)|*.dll";
                OFD.CheckFileExists = true;
                OFD.CheckPathExists = true;
                OFD.ShowDialog();

                textBox1.Text = OFD.FileName;
                DLLP = OFD.FileName;
            }
            catch (Exception ed)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ed.Message);
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DLLP = textBox1.Text;
        }

        private void flatButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process[] PC = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => (long)p.MainWindowHandle != 0).ToArray();
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            foreach (Process p in PC)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
            }
        }
        static readonly IntPtr INTPTR_ZERO = (IntPtr)0;
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(uint dwDesiredAccess, int bInheritHandle, GraphicsUnit dwProcessId);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr Module, string lpProcName);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] Buffer, uint size, int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] buffer, uint size, int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpThreadAttribute, IntPtr dwStackSize, IntPtr lpStartAddress, IntPtr lpParameter, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpThreadId);

        public static int Inject(string PN, string DLLP)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(DLLP)) { return 1; } //1 not exist

            uint _procId = 0;
            Process[] _procs = Process.GetProcesses();
            for (int i = 0; i < _procs.Length; i++)
            {
                if (_procs[i].ProcessName == PN)
                {
                    _procId = (uint)_procs[i].Id;
                }
            }

            if (_procId == 0) { return 2; } //2 not exist

            if (!SI(_procId, DLLP))
            {
                return 3; //3 inject fail
            }
            return 4; //4 inject success
        }
        public bool SI(uint P, string DLLP)
        {
            IntPtr hndProc = OpenProcess((0x2 | 0x8 | 0x10 | 0x20 | 0x400), 1, P);

            if (hndProc == INTPTR_ZERO) { return false; }

            IntPtr lpAddress = VirtualAllocEx(hndProc, (IntPtr)null, (IntPtr)DLLP.Length, (0x1000 | 0x2000), 0x40);

            if (lpAddress == INTPTR_ZERO)
            {
                return false;
            }

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DLLP);

            if (WriteProcessMemory(hndProc, lpAddress, bytes, (uint)bytes.Length, 0) == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }

            CloseHandle(hndProc);

            return true;
        }

        private IntPtr OpenProcess(int v1, int v2, uint p)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hndProc, IntPtr intPtr, IntPtr length, int v1, int v2)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void flatButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Result = Inject(comboBox1.Text, DLLP);

            if (Result == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File doesn't exist");
            }
            else if (Result == 2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Process doesn't exist");
            }    
            else if (Result == 3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Injection fail");
            }
            else if (Result == 4)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Injection Succeeded");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8U1ir.png)

Comment: `SI` method is non-static method and you are calling that method in `Inject` method which is static. That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: what would be the best solution I could do sir

Comment: The easiest solution is to make `SI` static like `Inject` is.